# Beginner's Apache mod_rewrite - use custom file for website root

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Plain and simple - I want user to get main.php file instead of index.php, when he enters website. Such a straightforward task has caused me a lot of pain, and couple of hours googling. Following does not work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /subdomain/main.php
```

This doesn't work either:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ http://localhost/subdomain/main.php
```

Where is the problem?

P.S. The rules are placed in `.htaccess` in `/subdomain` directory. I'm using WAMP, if it matters.

P.P.S. Logs show "File not found" message.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using Apache's [`DirectoryIndex` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) to accomplish this task?

Comment: No, just wasn't aware of it. Thanks, this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match URIs in the root directory, your .htaccess file has to be in the root directory, not in /subdirectory.

I agree that the best way to do this would be using the DirectoryIndex directive.

Answer (score 0):

Is mod_rewrite enabled in the first place? Unless something's changed since the last time I used Wampserver, it's off by default.

Click the WampServer icon in the system tray, mouse over `Apache`, then `Apache modules`. Find rewrite_module(or mod_rewrite) in the menu and click it. Then you'll need to restart all services.

Comment: Of course it's on.